# Submitting "complex" ASP.net forms using cURL&PHP

Tags: asp.net, forms, curl, post, gridview

I'm trying to create a bot to submit a ASP.net form using [cURL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) and PHP. I'm able to do this with simple forms but I got stuck with one email form that uses a grid. Looking the network traffic when submitting the form I found this as one of the parameters posted to the form:

> panForm$cbpEmail$FormLayout$grdFaleConoscoDestinatarios: {"selection":"T","callbackState":"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","groupLevelState":{},"keys":["201259","201260","201261","201262","201263","201264","201265","201266","201267","201268","201269","201270","201271","201272","201273","201274","201275","201276"]}

This data represents a grid that is part of the email form where user is able to select who will receive the email.

My question is how can I mimic what ASP.net do to create this data from the grid that is on the page to be able to submit the email form? Does anyone have information about this "callbackstate"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While waiting for useful answers, revisit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting a lot of times the same form I realized that I don't need to care about the callbackState. What is important in my case is properly set the selection attribute of this JSON (provided during the creation of the component on the page).

The selection attribute represents the state of the checkboxes in the grid. T means true and F false. selection="T" means only first row selected while selection="FTFT" represents 2nd and 4th rows selected. Remaining rows not represented in the selection attribute are false by default.

Best Regards